# Is the Complex Exponential the Only Eigenfunction of LTI Systems?

Tags: signal-processing, eigenfunctions

I've been studying Linear Time-Invariant (LTI) systems and came across the concept of eigenfunctions with respect to these systems. The literature often presents complex exponentials (as well as sines and cosines, by Euler's formula) as eigenfunctions of LTI systems. I understand that for an LTI system described by the operator $( \mathcal{H})$, an eigenfunction $( f )$ with eigenvalue $( \lambda )$ satisfies:

$$\mathcal{H}f = \lambda f$$

And for the case of complex exponentials, we have:

$$\mathcal{H}e^{st} = H(s)e^{st}$$

where $$H(s) $$ is the transfer function of the system.

However, is there a formal proof that the complex exponential is the *only* eigenfunction of such systems? Or are there other functions that can also satisfy the eigenfunction condition for LTI systems? If possible, I would appreciate a detailed explanation or a direction towards resources that tackle this proof.

Comment: possibly related (at least in spirit):https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4726785/617446

Comment: @user619894 Thanks but I don't see it related enough

Comment: It's an example of a non exponential eigenfunction even though the operator is time invariant.

Comment: @user619894 if all square integrable functions can be expressed as a linear combination of complex exponentials (Fourier transform), does that mean that all functions are LTI eigenfunctions?

Comment: I think that if there are degeneracies in the eigen values then finite combinations of exponentials are permitted